# React.js variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use a variable starting with a small letter, the page is showing nothing. If I change the variable name to start with uppercase (HelloWorld) the page is showing the content.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
 var helloWorld = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
                return (
                    <div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    </div>
                    );
    }
 });

 React.render(<helloWorld/> , document.body);
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of React v0.12., upper-case components are the React convention for distinguishing between components and HTML tags.

From the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) under the **HTML Tags vs. React Components** header:

> To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts with an upper-case letter:
>
> ```
> var MyComponent = React.createClass({/*...*/});
> var myElement = <MyComponent someProperty={true} />;
> React.render(myElement, document.getElementById('example'));
> ```
>
> React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish between local component classes and HTML tags.